# Change label text in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I added a label to my NavigationBar with this code:

```
let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

let moneyFrame = CGRect(x: 330, y: 0, width: (navigationBar?.frame.width)!/2, height: (navigationBar?.frame.height)!)

let moneyLabel = UILabel(frame: moneyFrame)

moneyLabel.text = "\(money)"

navigationBar?.addSubview(moneyLabel)
```

The problem is: when I want to change the value of the variable "money", I always came with the solution to add another label. I just want to change the text of the label in the NavigationBar.

Comment: Just declare an instance of moneyLabel in ViewController class and add this label of navigationBar. After that whenever you need to change the navigation title use that label variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class scope define a label like this:

```
var moneyLabel: UILabel?
```

then in your function or wherever the code you posted sits in the class, do this:

```
func myFunctionThatSetupNavigationLabel() {
    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    let moneyFrame = CGRect(x: 330, y: 0, width: 
    (navigationBar?.frame.width)!/2, height: (navigationBar?.frame.height)!)

    moneyLabel = UILabel(frame: moneyFrame)

    moneyLabel.text = "\(money)"

    navigationBar?.addSubview(moneyLabel)
}
```

Now just add this function to edit the title label:

```
func updateTitle(title: String) {
    if let myTitleView = self.moneyLabel {
        myTitleView.text = title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the label to the navigation bar as a custom view.

In the class scope define a label:

```
var label = UILabel()
```

then in viewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textlabel = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = textlabel
    label.text = "money"
    }
```

then whenever you want to change the text label you could simply just write the next code:

```
label.text = "whatever you want"
```